# Recover space from CSS3's scaleY transform

Tags: html, css, transform

I'm doing a scaleY on a div, and though visually it is working the way I want, the page is still acting like it is it's original height. I'm shrinking it, and don't want empty space above and below it. I know I can probably hack this together with negative margins or something but I'm wondering if there is a better way like I don't know about to have the page naturally collapse into the freed up space from the transform.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

CSS transforms do not change the layout of the page, so all elements with transforms will take up as much space as it does without a transformation on it. That is the beauty of transformations. If you want to shrink the element, and have the page change then you will want to use the height CSS on the element.

Comment: This doesn't really help, as if you shrink the height it reformats the element, rather than showing it scaled.

Comment: I would call this an inconvenience, not a beauty :)